# How to remove environment prefix in Powershell console

Tags: powershell, terminal, oh-my-posh

Does anybody knows how I can remove (venv) prefix that is displayed in my Powershell Terminal window? I know that this is purely cosmetic, but I'd love to remove it since I'm using Oh My Posh.

I've attached screenshot.[image]

Comment: I think you will have to modify your prompt function in your profile.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've found the best solution (for my case at least).

Simply add: `$env:VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT = 1` to $PROFILE

Comment: This was the most robust way to override the env indicator for me

Comment: The only civilized way.

Comment: Thx for your awesome anwser.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like the python environment set by conda, which modifies your prompt function when being initialized.

Search for all the possible powershell profiles in your host:
`$PROFILE | Format-List -Force`

Then look for the part where it says `#region conda initialize` and modify it.

Alternatively you can search for the `ps1` file that does this, for me it's `C:\Users\Username\Miniconda3\shell\condabin\conda-hook.ps1` but ymmv.

I also use oh-my-posh, and display the environment on the right:

```
     {
       "foreground": "lightRed",
       "properties": {
         "display_mode": "always",
         "display_version": false,
         "display_virtual_env": true,
         "prefix":"",
         "postfix": "\uE235 "
       },
       "type": "python",
       "style": "plain"
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a `prompt` function in your `$profile` (not by default but if you have a customized prompt you will). You will have to modify it to remove the code that writes `(venv)` in your prompt.

Answer (score -1):

Go to the "C:\Program Files\Python310\Lib\venv\scripts\common" (your Python installation folder might be different)

- Find a file "Activate.ps1".
- Open the file with any editor of your choice.
- Find the line with following code (approximately line 232)

```js
function global:prompt {
    Write-Host -NoNewline -ForegroundColor Green "($_PYTHON_VENV_PROMPT_PREFIX) "
    _OLD_VIRTUAL_PROMPT
}
```

- Remove this variable with brackets **($_PYTHON_VENV_PROMPT_PREFIX) ** you can leave only double quotes.
- After that your the function should look like this.

```js
function global:prompt {
    Write-Host -NoNewline -ForegroundColor Green ""
    _OLD_VIRTUAL_PROMPT
}
```

- At last, recreate the environment.